# Create a shared or common email address for entire organization

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I've a G Suite set up within my company. Every user has been added together with their personal email, etc.

As a last thing I want to create some shared or common email addresses for different employees. For example, *all* employees should receive emails when sending to `all@company.com` and some employees should also receive emails within their departments: `marketing`, `it`, `support` and so on.

I've looked at [*Groups*](https://support.google.com/a/answer/126169?hl=en) in G Suite but it is not quite what I'm searching for, and it's way more complex than just a shared email address, but for the life of me I can't figure out where I'm going to add this.

Comment: I also need the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create a common email (team email) for an organization in G Suite: via **groups** or via a **new user**.

The **groups** approach doesn't add to your monthly bill. However, it's slightly more complicated to setup.  We created a guide in our Gmail tips section to help:
https://alphastack.io/business-email-hosting/gmail-tips

The **new user** approach involves adding a new user in G Suite just like you would add a new team member in the admin console.  Once setup, you can setup forwarding from this email address to all of your team members.  You could also allow team members to login to this account to manage it directly.  The advantage of this approach is that you will have a dedicated inbox for all incoming emails to this address.  Note that this approach will add to your monthly bill ($5 per user per month).